# How do I import Unreal Models? (smite)

Tags: unreal-engine

I'm new to the program so this is probably much easier that I think it is but I've been trying to import into blender the smite god models, I used UEModel to extract them into .psa and .psk files (as well as some other formats though I'm not sure what they're for) however when I try to import any of them into blender, no matter what import 'mode' I select, I can't see any of the files, only the sub folders.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are trying to import .psa/.psk files? Are you using this add-on: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Unreal_psk_psa ?

Comment: Right now I realise I needed to enable the add-on... which is done now but I get an error message http://i66.tinypic.com/35hkck0.png and I don't understand what that means at all

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default addon that comes with Blender, this is why you have errors. It's outdated, you want to get and use befzz's updated importer, though it does have issues with bone names and animation on some models.